# "Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined" while calling a method of one component from another via params.context in Angular 8

Tags: angular8, angular-components, angular-module, angular-lifecycle-hooks

```
export class ChildMessageRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any;
   @ViewChild(SecComponent, { static: false }) accComponent: SecComponent;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;

  }
  public loadRequestsHistory() {
       this.params.context.AccountBatchAuditComponent.loadRequestsHistory('36');
  }
}
```

I am trying to call method of SecComponent from ChildMessageRenderer. @ViewChild is throughing error in the console. Can someone help on this issue?
[image]
[image]

Comment: check if adding SecComponent in declarations of AccountBatchModule fixes the issue?